# Is there a way to tell if a function in JavaScript is getting over written?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is there a way to tell if a function I've written is getting overwritten or redefined? For example, say a guy named Jack has the function below:

```
// Jack's function on team 1
function doSomething() {
    // doing things
}
```

and one day he finds out that a teammate in the north pole of planet Zaxxon has used the same function name:

```
// Zaxar's function on team 2
function doSomething() {
    // doing something else
}
```

As you can see Zaxar and Jack are using the same function name. Neither Zaxar nor John discovered the problem until 6 months into the project. They know they can put an alert in their function and check it at runtime but let's say Zaxar and Jack both have 2 trillion functions and they are using 1 million JavaScript libraries and they realize it's impractical to put alerts in each function.

Is there a way to help Zaxar and Jack discover if there are any name collisions at runtime? Or is there a setting that will tell the JavaScript engine to throw errors on name collisions?

**More information**
I'm loading in a few libraries and I think that one of them is using the same function name as me. So in this example, there really isn't another developer I can correlate with. It's finding out if the library(s) that I load in are using the same function names and preventing something like this from happening down the line.

Comment: Maybe JSHint would help? dunoo... But my advice, they separately go through the code and put all functions in an object (namespace), and replace all calls with the prefix. It shouldn't take long with a decent editor.

Comment: The real solution would be for each developer or each part of the project to be working in their own namespace.

Comment: Suitable name selection and good communication will avoid such issues. Presumably if they are working on the same project and have a function with the same name, then it does the same thing. So one should be removed from the project. If the project got this far with that big an issue, it's a failure of project management (communication, design and testing have all failed).

Comment: you can get the string of each function, make an md5 of of it, and compare to the signatures on the other machine. now that firefox leaves function source alone, everything should match.

Answer (score 1):

Although the suggestion on namespacing is apt, you may also be interested in the `writable` and `configurable` properties of [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) descriptors if you wanted to prevent overwriting of specific functions:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "myUnchangeableFunction", {value: function () {
    alert("Can't change me");
}, writable: false, configurable: false});

/*
function myUnchangeableFunction () { // TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'myUnchangeableFunction'
    alert('change?');
}

var myUnchangeableFunction = function () { // TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'myUnchangeableFunction'
    alert('change?');
};
*/

myUnchangeableFunction();
```

You should check support in the browsers you wish to support, however, as some older browsers might not support this functionality.